# Reading a memory register returns incorrect value?

Tags: c, embedded

I'm trying to read a memory register and to check one flag in this register. I can check the value inside the register using an ST-LINK/V2 debugger. I'm working on STM8/128-EVAL board.

Following is a sample of my code:

```
#define ADDR(addr_off)  (*(volatile uint8_t*)(0x5000 + (addr_off)))
#define CAN_MCSR        ADDR(0x428)   // control/status register
#define TXOK            (1 << 3)      // Transmission OK    (CAN_MCSR)

uint8_t send(void)
{
    volatile uint8_t state;
    state = CAN_MCSR;

    if(CAN_MCSR & TXOK)             // Line 1
        return 1;   // Succeeded    // Line 2
    else                    
        return 0;   // Failed       // Line 3
}
```

I'm confused because when I set a breakpoint in `Line 1`, I see using the debugger that the value inside the `CAN_MCSR` register is `0x0C` while the value of `state` variable is `0x01` although I didn't modify this variable anywhere else in the code. When I step forward to execute the if statement, it succeeds and `Line 2` is executed.

However, if I set a breakpoint in `Line 2` and onther in `Line 3` while there is no breakpoint in `Line 0`, the if condition fails and `Line 3` is executed.

What can cause this problem?

**UPDATE**

I guess it turned out to be timing issue as some comments suggested. I have tried the following snippet:

```
state = CAN_MCSR;                  // state = 0x01
if(CAN_MCSR & TXOK)
{
    state = CAN_MCSR;              // state = 0x0C
    return state;                  // Succeeded
}
else
{
    return state;                   // Failed
}
```

But I'm still confused, when I add a breakpoint in Line 1, why my code says that `state` equals to `1` while the debugger says that the register's value equals to `0x0C`?

**UPDATE 2**

As Clifford and Lundin suggested, I read the register once and save the value in `state` then test this variable. And to solve the timing issue, I keep waiting in a while loop until the flag is set. I know that this is a very bad solution as it keeps the CPU busy but it works for now and I'm planning to use interrupt as a next step. If someone can suggest a better solution, his answer will be appreciated.

```
do
{
    state = CAN_MCSR;
}while(!(state & TXOK));

return 1;
```

Comment: Did you check your generated code whether it actually reads anything into `state`? As this variable is never used, it could be removed. Can you single step on assembler level and verify what is really loaded into registers?

Comment: Perhaps handling the breakpoint on Line 1 allowed more time for the flag to be set, but otherwise was not set, as trapped at Line 3. Why don't you use `state & TXOK`?

Comment: If the CAN peripheral is still active in stop mode, so that the registers may update even though the program isn't running, then this behavior is no wonder. How this works is different from hardware to hardware and it might be configurable.

Comment: @Gerhardh It is a volatile qualified variable so it may _not_ be removed and the compiler must generate a read instruction.

Comment: @Lundin I totally agree regarding the read instruction for `CAN_MCSR`. But what about storing the data in a local variable `state` that is not used afterwards? Sorry, I wasn't precise enough.

Comment: Your function is reading the `CAN_MCSR` register twice. There is no reason why its content can't change bewteen the two reads (after all you are waiting for the flag to go high) and adding a breakpoint at the second read might pretty well guarantee that to happen.

Comment: @Gerhardh `state` is volatile and it is used. The program will not likely unstack it before the end of the function.

Comment: @Lundin. At least I have seen that debug information was invalid immediately after a variable was used the last time. This might cause a wrong value being displayed in debugger. Additionally if a register is used, it might be invalid as well after that line.

Comment: Stopping the debugger at line 1 makes you look at an uninitialized stack value which is simply garbage. From the code you attached I can only think of some timing dependencies that set values in the register you are trying to read.

Comment: @Lundin Could you please elaborate?

Comment: please post the disassembly

Comment: Often peripheral register status bits have _reset on read_ semantics. If you are watching the register in the debugger, you are reading it independently of the code and thereby changing its value.  You should place breakpoints _after_ the code has retreived the status, and be wary of reading peripheral registers in the debugger, and consider that that may change the value read by the code.

Comment: ... further in your code you read CAN_MCSR twice.  The condition should test state, not CAN_MCSR because it is volatile, and the first read may have caused it to change.  Note that declaring state volatile serves no purpose.

Comment: @SalahuddinAshraf What Clifford says above ^. The CAN controller is an independent piece of hardware from the CPU core and the registers might change even if the CPU is stopped. Typically every peripheral hardware has an option such as "freeze in stop mode", which you must enable if you wish to debug those hardware registers through single step.

Comment: @Clifford Declaring `state` volatile might serve the purpose of making it stack allocated rather than register allocated, so that you can "watch" it in the debugger.

Comment: @Lundin : when that happens, I generally inspect the registers.

Comment: I've tried reading `CAN_MCSR` and saving its value in `state` and then checking `state` in the if statement. Doing this, it always fails even if I put a breakpoint in Line 1 or Line 2 or Line 3. However, when I directly check the register in the if statement, it succeeds. Therefore, I think the point in my case is when to read the register and not how many times you read it. Because I read the register a third time in the code in the **UPDATE** and the value looks like to remain the same as when reading it in the second time in the code. Am I right?

Comment: I think the solution would be to use an interrupt instead of trying to guess when is the right time to read the register.

Comment: @SalahuddinAshraf The first read by the program `state = CAN_MCSR` is the correct one, the rest is just incorrect results caused by the above mentioned phenomenons. You should only read the register once in this function.

Comment: `volatile uint8_t state;
    state = CAN_MCSR;` Any **good** reason you made the variable `volatile`? And use reasonable names. `send` does not _send_ anything.

Comment: And without looking into the datasheet: Does a read to `CAN_MCSR`clear the register or so? For some registers, this is common.